# Discord.js collector not ending, ignoring its keys to stop

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, collectors

### Hello I have an issue

So I wrote this code to give ranks on discord,
but my message collector is ignoring its keys to stop collecting.
Can anyone help me fix this issue?

Code:

```
client.on("messageCreate", message => {
if (message.content === '!rank lol'){
    message.channel.send('Is Yuumi a MID laner?')
}
const collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, {max: 1}, {maxProcessed: 1}, {time: 8000})
collector.on('collect', message => {
    if (message.content == "yes") {
        message.channel.send("No rank for you xd!")
        collector.stop()
    } else if (message.content == "no"){
        message.channel.send("You have got the LOL rank!")
        message.member.roles.add("783023112681422849")
        collector.stop
    }


})
```

})

**Discord.js documentation:**

*You can control when a collector ends by supplying additional option keys when creating a collector:

time: Amount of time in milliseconds the collector should run for

max: Number of messages to successfully pass the filter

maxProcessed: Number of messages encountered (no matter the filter result)*

Answer (score 0):

You passed multiple options seperatly. You need to pass them all in one.

```
const collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, { max: 1, maxProcessed: 1, time: 8000 });
```

Comment: Hello I did what you said and it still collects forever, do you have any other idea?

Comment: One thing I also noticed that you create the collector outside the if statement, so basically everytime the messageCreate event gets triggered, it creates a new collector

Comment: I don't exactly know how to make it work I tried everything can you help me?

Comment: Not quite sure but try to put the whole collector code in your if (message.content === '!rank lol') { HERE } so it doesn’t create a new collector everytime some send a message. Then also correct what a mentioned in my answer and then everything looks ok for me